# Renaming multiple files - first by finding the files in a set of subdirectories and then matching file names to a list containing the new file names

Tags: bash, file, find, rename, mv

I have a set of files that are organised across a large number of sub-directories, for example:

```
/Image/Square001/Data
/Image/Square002/Data
/Image/Square003/Data
```

and so on.

All the files within these directories have a similar type of name but have different numbers within the name.

```
Triangle_284852_Data_222844_222846_20220302_034926.tiff
Triangle_284908_Data_222841_222843_20220302_035350.tiff
Triangle_284908_Data_222845_222843_20220302_035350.tiff
```

I had like to rename all of these files to include another number. The correct number needed has already been appended to a given filename within a text file (temp_names.txt)

```
Triangle_284852_Data_222844_222846_20220302_034926_1.tiff
Triangle_284908_Data_222841_222843_20220302_035350_63.tiff
Triangle_284908_Data_222845_222843_20220302_035350_12.tiff
```

I am trying to write a bash script to rename the files in the directory to match those in temp_names.txt

I think I need to use the find command, set up a while loop for each file to be matched based on their similarity and be renamed, but I am having trouble getting this right.

In the past, I have used something like:

```
for file in ./Image/Square*/Data/*.tiff
do 
    read line
    mv "${file}" "${line}"
done < temp_names.txt
```

When the files are all in the same sub-directory and are read in the same order as they appear in my text file. However, this is not the case for these files and I need a new approach. I have been trying some variants of starting like this:

```
find /Images/Square*/Data/ -type f -name .tiff |
    while IFS= read -d '' file_name; do
```

But I am unsure whether I should be using `rename` or `mv` in the next line, how to match the common parts between the filename in the directory and in the text file, and then how to add a changeable string (the number at the end) to the file name.

Comment: I wrote a script to do what you require and hit a wall.  Look at your 2nd and 3rd file.  They have the same name.  When you look for these filenames in temp_names.txt, you get two different results.  How do you want to proceed in such cases?

Comment: Ah that's my mistake, I've just copied the example twice. All the files are unique.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script to do your requirement:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "Triangle_*.tiff" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    # extract the filename, without extension
    filename=$(basename "${file%.*}")
    # Find that in the temp_names.txt file
    newfilename=$(grep "$filename" temp_names.txt)
    # extract the path of the file
    filepath=$(dirname "$file")
    # rename the file
    mv -v "$file" "$filepath/$newfilename"
done
```

- The `find` is recursive, so it will handle all files.
- From each file, remove its extension, then `grep` for the name in the list of new filenames.
- Since the file could be in any sub-directory, the path is extracted from the file found by `find`.
- The `mv` changes the name of the file to the new name, under the same directory as the original file.
- I put option `-v` to the `mv` to get some log of what is done.  But you can remove it if not required.

Comment: This is perfect - thank you for taking the time to help me with this. A very clear explanation as well.